# How can I place two statements on same line?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="index.shtml">Home</a>

<p id="dt"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = "hello";
</script>
```

I just need both statements on the same line. This must be simple!! (but I cant do it!) Thanks

Comment: You could set `display:inline-block` on the paragraph

Comment: `<p>` makes a new paragraph in a new line by default. Use a `<div>` as container instead or change the `<p>` properties.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I knew it was simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is representing a paragraph and therefore is (usually) a block element. For what you are doing, you would be better served with using an inline element like `span`.

Making the element inline will lead to both being displayed on the same line. If switching the tag is not an option, use css to set `display:inline` on the paragraph.

Comment: <Style>p.ex2 {display: inline;}
 </style>

 <a href="index.shtml">Home</a>

  <p class="ex2"id="dt" display:inline-block></p>

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag will create a new line by default. One way to prevent this is CSS `display: inline`.

```
<style>
 #dt {display: inline;}
</style> 

<a href="index.shtml">Home</a> 

<p id="dt"></p>

<script>
 document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = "hello";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.shtml" style=' white-space: nowrap;'>Home</a>


<div id="dt" style='display: inline-block;'></div>

<script >
document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = "hello";
</script>
```

[Reference](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-force-html-elements-to-stay-on-the-same-line)